# ContentBlockbyKey Default Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

since i am uncertain which way is right and i dont want to run into problems that may occure, i want to make sure i am doing everything right with the command ContentBlockbyKey.

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbykey.htm) the fourth parameter of ContentBlockbyKey is a string value. According to that, i would think that this code would be correct:

```
%%[

Set @temp_ap = [SomeFieldOfDataExtenson]
Set @ap = Uppercase(@temp_ap)
Set @strContentBlock = Concat("EMPLOYEE_",@ap,"_BLOCK")
Set @strDefaultContentBlock = "EMPLOYEE_9999_BLOCK"

IF NOT EMPTY(@ap) THEN
    Outputline(ContentBlockbyKey(@strContentBlock,"",TRUE,@strDefaultContentBlock,@status))
    IF @status == -1 THEN
        RaiseError(Concat("Error: The ContentBlock ",@strContentBlock," has not been found."))
ELSE
    RaiseError(Concat("Error: The Employee field is empty."))
ENDIF   
]%%
```

But if you have any advice on improvements on this code please let me know:)

What makes me bother is the official documentation of [ContentBlockByName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyname.htm) because the fourth parameter is filled with another use of the ContentBlockByName function.

```
%%=ContentBlockByName("Content Builder\Opt Out Form 2","",0,ContentBlockByName("Content Builder\Opt Out Form Default"))=%%
```

Why would you use the ContentBlockByName function on the fourth parameter on this example? [maybe to retrieve the customer key or sth?]
Do i have to do this on the code above with ContentBlockbyKey aswell?

Btw: Does it matter if you write ContentBlockByKey or ContentBlockbyKey? Are functions case sensitive or insensitive?

Comment: The use of the ContentBlockByName() at the 4th parameter is to pull in a default content area. For instance, if you had logic to call in a content area based on language, say if FR pulls in ContentBlockByName("French"), if SP pulls in ContentBlockByName("Spanish") and you set the 4th parameter to ContentBlockByName("English"). In cases where data passes an unexpected value for language, like "RU" and ContentBlockByName("Russian"), wasn't created, it'll then pull in ContentBlockByName("English"). 

Functions are not case sensative.

Comment: Thanks for the info about case insensitive functions. But regarding the fourth parameter: Yes i do understand that the fourth parameter pulls the default area, but the value that is placed inside the fourth parameter is a FUNCTION when you see the ContentBlockByName documentation not a string. Whats right here?